# I created a new user but I can't perform any actions on new user

Tags: linux, permissions, users

So I created a user named `test` and then I tried to make a directory in it but the permission was denied although the user test has all permissions.

```
tambkto@X250:/home$ ls
amna  tambkto
tambkto@X250:/home$ sudo useradd test -m
tambkto@X250:/home$ ls
amna  tambkto  test
tambkto@X250:/home$ cd test/
tambkto@X250:/home/test$ ls
examples.desktop
tambkto@X250:/home/test$ mkdir app
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘app’: Permission denied
tambkto@X250:/home/test$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 8980 Apr 16 2018 examples.desktop
tambkto@X250:/home/test$ cd ..
tambkto@X250:/home$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 test    test    4096 Apr 23 05:41 amna
drwxr-xr-x 23 tambkto tambkto 4096 Apr 24 00:09 tambkto 
drwxr-xr-x  2 test    test    4096 Apr 24 00:12 test
tambkto@X250:/home$
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first switch to the user `test`:

```
su test
Password:
test@X250:/home/test$ mkdir app
```

Answer (score 2):

You have successfully created a new user called `test` and their home directory.  You are getting errors when attempting to create directories in the user's home directory because you don't have permission to do that with your current `tambkto` user.

You need to log in as the new `test` user to create directories and files in their home directory.  To allow the `test` user to log in, you will have to assign a password to the account using the `passwd` command as root:

```bsh
sudo passwd test
```

Alternatively, you may use `sudo` to temporarily change into the `test` identity for the sake of your `mkdir` command:

```bsh
sudo -u test mkdir ~test/app
```

Answer (score 0):

Why should the user `tambkto` have write permissions in the home directory of the user `test`...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/335861)

Comment: Actually, it _implies_ the answer, but I think if you post it as such, you should really elaborate it a little more; otherwise I would agree with @user1794469 that it should be a comment.

Comment: TBH for OP at 1 rep and obviously a new convert, I would tend to agree with @adminbee. Though for others I would let it ride. Throw OP a bone.